# nsmutablearray insertobject atindex:0 not working

Tags: nsmutablearray, uibarbuttonitem

Can someone please help me understand why the insertobject atindex:0 line is failing to add anything to the nsmutablearray? Thanks.

```
- (void)setSplitViewBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)splitViewBarButtonItem
{
    if (_splitViewBarButtonItem != splitViewBarButtonItem) {
        NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
        if (_splitViewBarButtonItem) [toolbarItems removeObject:_splitViewBarButtonItem];
        if (splitViewBarButtonItem) {
            [toolbarItems insertObject:splitViewBarButtonItem atIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"setSplitViewBarButtonItem: toolbarItems has %u objects",toolbarItems.count);
        }
        self.toolbar.items = toolbarItems;
        _splitViewBarButtonItem = splitViewBarButtonItem;
    }
}
```

toolbar is a private property defined earlier in the same .m file thus

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIToolbar *toolbar;
```

I have also tried replacing the line

```
NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
```

with

```
NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
toolbarItems = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
```

but still nothing is added to toolbarItems. Debugger consistently shows splitViewBarButtonItem to be non-null and my NSLog keeps printing zero.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the insertObject line working by replacing the if (_splitViewBarButton)... line with this

```
if (_splitViewBarButtonItem) {
    toolbarItems = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [toolbarItems removeObject:_splitViewBarButtonItem];
} else {
    toolbarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

In other words, if _splitViewBarButtonItem was set (there is a bar button), remove it. Otherwise, need to alloc init it.

My problem now is the assignment

```
self.toolbar.items = toolbarItems;
```

is not working and the bar button is now showing up on the details view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ok actually what I really needed was to have my toolbar property be an IBOutlet, ie changing

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIToolbar *toolbar;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
```

With this change, my originally posted code works as is. I suppose toolbar was not getting instantiated properly when not defined as IBOutlet.